# Is there a way to display SVG Symbols in an Attribute Table in a Print Layout?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, svg

I'm working on a trail map that contains both hiking and mountain biking trails. In the Attribute Table for the Trails, I'd like to have a column that displays a bicycle SVG if mountain biking is allowed on the trail.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm also open to the idea that this is not the best way to show this information and am open to other ideas (different trail styling, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Only a legend, here is a quick mock up of bike/hike trail.

All the data is in a gpx route - the **symbol** has been assigned to the trail only if the bike attribute is there.
[image]

This done via the add svg marker.
[image]

QGIS 3.14 used here.